# Does ORDER BY clause slows down the query?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, query-optimization

Does the ORDER BY clause slows down the query performance ??? How much will it effect if the column is indexed as against when it is not.

Comment: There isn't enough information here to provide an adequate answer. Anytime you add ordering to a query it will affect performance because the results have to be ordered. The amount of impact however is NOT a static answer. There a number of factors involved.

Comment: I can see this being closed as too broad, simply because the correct answer to this is "it depends", as in, it depends on too many variables to correctly answer it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

@JamesZ is correct.  There are many things to consider when adding the `order by` clause to your query.  For instance if you did a `select top 10 * from dbo.Table order by field` with let's say 10,000,000 rows would cause the query to spill into tempdb as it spooled the entire table to tempdb and then after sorting by your non-indexed field would then return the 10 rows.  If you did the same select without the sort, results would return almost immediately.

It's very important to know how your tables are indexed before issuing an `order by` clause.  `CTRL-M` is your friend in **SSMS**.

Comment: Thanks for a detailed explanation.

Answer (score 3):

If there is a sort operator in the query plan (and there is more than 1 row), yes, it has an affect. If the data is already in the order you need it (either clustered index, or non-clustered index that has all the fields that the query needs in correct order), the sorting might not be needed, but other operations in the plan might still cause sorting to be done to be sure that the data is still in the correct order.

How much does if affect, well test it. Take the sorting away and compare the performance.

Answer (score 1):

It is better to test. You can use actual execution plan.
Here is a simple ORDEY BY but the additional cost is 4 times the original one

[image]